# LoginButton.java error - trouble getting started with facebook sdk on Android

Tags: android, facebook

i am having trouble with the facebook sdk. I use Intellij Idea, and I managed to add the sdk to the project and at least getting it compiled.

So I start with a blank project with a single activity and i add a LoginButton so that my Layout.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
            />

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first problem is, I get this message at the UI preview window:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F060006.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getColor(BridgeResources.java:185)
    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:237)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:169)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:553)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:553)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:626)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:575)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:521)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:516)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

So it looks like there is trouble with the R file, but, anyways, it still compiles.

As soon as the app runs on the emulator, it crashes with this stack:

```
05-02 19:15:35.073    2023-2023/com.Jam D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-02 19:15:35.453    2023-2029/com.Jam D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-02 19:15:36.014    2023-2023/com.Jam D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb91d7290, tid 2023
05-02 19:15:36.514    2023-2023/com.Jam W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-02 19:15:36.564    2023-2023/com.Jam D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-02 19:15:36.644    2023-2036/com.Jam W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1d8cb20)
05-02 19:15:36.644    2023-2036/com.Jam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.Jam, PID: 2023
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:372)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:667)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:664)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am new to Android so I have no clue what to do. I mean, my code will throw all sorts of exceptions :p but I have no clue as I why facebook SDK code would throw a null exception.

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing same problem:

I was putting my app id as this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="MY_APP_ID"/>
```

but what it should have been:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

I never thought this could create such an error. They should put this as warning in their tutorial I guess!

Give it a try. If this is not the solution then it should be something related to App ID. You might not have added keyhash to your app. Follow each step in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) tutorial and don't skip any.

If it still doesn't solve the problem compare facebook related with facebook samples packed with the SDK.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem some time back and for me the problem had to do with wrong meta data name. Make sure you get it right.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

instead of

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.Application"   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```