# FacebookSDK cant find resources (Intellij idea)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, facebook-android-sdk

I want to use Facbook login for the app I'm currently developing. Sadly I think I messed something up by adding the SDK to my projekt and now I get the error

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F060006.
```

when I try to add a facebook loginbutton.

I thought I had done everything like in the [getting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) but since it's for eclipse I'm not quite sure.

Has anyone had a similar problem and managed to fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24053027/1469004)

Summary:
If you have a value like this (in `AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="MY_APP_ID"/>
```

Make sure it points at a resource value like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Comment: well, need more info then, like project settings screenshots, or perhaps better - put the project on github and it will be easier to resolve.